# Get the result of the Webservice request using Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit and I'm in touch with my webservice but I can not get an answer and the field I want. Example: campo1 and assign to a variable and print it. 
I think I'm not calling onResponse properly, as it's coming as null

Send JSON:

```
{
    "select":"select id || ' | ' ||senha_terminal,nome,login_web,null,5,null n2,7,senha_terminal,senha_web,data_inclusao from usuario where id in (3257) order by id desc"
}
```

Expected response:

```
[
    {
        "campo1": "3257 | 74327",
        "campo2": "Sidnei",
        "campo3": "sidnei01",
        "campo4": null,
        "campo5": 5,
        "campo6": null,
        "campo7": 7,
        "campo8": "74327",
        "campo9": "56c07af798f309dbd75822a849ce47b6",
        "campo10": "2012-02-08T11:00:06"
    }
]
```

I would like to get field1 and assign in a variable response.

**Main:**

```
package com.example.romeu.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.converter.scalars.ScalarsConverterFactory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<SelectModel> {

    public Button btnConsultar;
    Call<SelectModel> call;
    Response<SelectModel> response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.URL_BASE)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
        try
        {
            JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
            paramObject.put("select", "select id || ' | ' ||senha_terminal,nome,login_web,null,5,null n2,7,senha_terminal,senha_web,data_inclusao from usuario where id in (3257) order by id desc");
            onResponse(call, response);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<SelectModel> call, Response<SelectModel> response)
    {
        String resposta = response.body().getCampo1();
        Log.i("MSG", resposta);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<SelectModel> call, Throwable t) {
    }
}
```

**ApiInterface:**

```
    package com.example.romeu.myapplication;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

/**
 * Created by romeu on 01/03/18.
 */

public interface ApiInterface {
    String URL_BASE = "https://services-dev.redetendencia.com.br/api-rest";

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("select")
    Call<SelectModel> getSelect(@Body String body);

}
```

**Model:**

```
package com.example.romeu.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by romeu on 01/03/18.
 */

class SelectModel {
    public String campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4,campo5,campo6,campo7,campo8,campo9,campo10;

    public SelectModel(){}

    //Getters


    public String getCampo1() {
        return campo1;
    }

    public String getCampo2() {
        return campo2;
    }

    public String getCampo3() {
        return campo3;
    }

    public String getCampo4() {
        return campo4;
    }

    public String getCampo5() {
        return campo5;
    }

    public String getCampo6() {
        return campo6;
    }

    public String getCampo7() {
        return campo7;
    }

    public String getCampo8() {
        return campo8;
    }

    public String getCampo9() {
        return campo9;
    }

    public String getCampo10() {
        return campo10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to achieve an async request. But the callback does not work this way:

```
onResponse(call, response);
```

you are actually just invoking `onResponse( .. )` directly with `null` response. Also, you do not construct `Call` at all it is also `null`. Replace above line with:

```
Call<SelectModel> call = apiInterface.getSelect(paramObject.toString());
call.enqueue(MainActivity.this);
```

**Note**: `paramObject.toString()` is only a suggestion. I am not sure how it is supposed to be attached to the request body. Maybe you can put only that string without any `JsonObject`.

That enqueues async request which when gets response, will invoke `onResponse( .. )`.